# How to add a title and a snippet to Google's MyLocation pin (Google Maps Android API v2)

Tags: java, android, location, overlay, google-maps-markers

Here's my code:

```
// Declare map
private GoogleMap map;
...
// Initialise map
map = ((MapFragment) findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
...
// Set location
map.setMyLocation(true);
```

Upon Google's MyLocation pin being pressed, I want a title and snippet to appear. With a normal marker this can be achieved by:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
.title("My Location")
.snippet("You are here!")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));
```

Where .title("") sets a title and .snippet("") sets a snippet; however I am unsure how to do this with Google's MyLocation pin.

Can someone please explain how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I would like to know.
I tried to add a marker on the myLocation icon using the code:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
.title("You are here"));
```

latLng gets its data from latitude and longitude doubles

```
double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();       
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

This adds a marker to the screen however it is way out of sync with the MyLocation marker. I think it has something to do with the location eg. it is getting the location from network or wireless instead of GPS.

This has been doing my head in for days and I would love to find out why.